# How can I change the language of errors in laravel 5.1 dynamically

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have been using the helper

> app()->setLocale(session('lang'));

However, I can get to change the languages of views but the languages of errors still continues reading of

> \config\app.php  locale => ‘es’

That means that always show the same language.

How can i change it also dynamically?

[image]

The problems is that the partial view that prints the errors always print in the same language.

Here is the code that i have.

**\resources\views\layout.blade.php**

```
@lang('messages.project')
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="{{ url('lang', ['en']) }}">En</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{ url('lang', ['es']) }}">Es</a></li>
</ul>
```

**\app\Http\routes.php**

```
Route::get('lang/{lang}', 'NotesController@changeLang')->where([ 'lang' => 'en|es']); 

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () { 
Route::get('notes', 'NotesController@index'); 
Route::get('notes/create', 'NotesController@create'); 
});
```

**\app\Http\Controllers\NotesController.php**

```
public function changeLang($lang)
{
   session(['lang' => $lang]);
   return Redirect::back();
}
```

**\app\Http\Middleware\LangMiddleware.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   if (!empty(session('lang'))) {
     app()->setLocale(session('lang'));
   }
   return $next($request);
}
```

**\resources\views\partials\errors.blade.php**

```
<ul>
   @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
      <li>{{ $error }}</li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: How do you mean ***dynamic**?  Do you mean without reloading the page, with an `XMLHttpRequest`, something else?  Please define the parameters of this change.

Comment: Hello Nicholas. It isn't about Ajax request. I have two links

routes.php
Route::get('lang/{lang}', 'NotesController@changeLang')->where([ 'lang' => 'en|es']);

Comment: Neither the screenshot nor the code demonstrate where the locale change is happening.  In addition, your question doesn't explain where in the code or application you'd like the locale change to occur.

Comment: Hello Nicholas. It isn't about Ajax request. I have two links

resources\views\layout.blade.php
<li><a href="{{ url('lang', ['en']) }}">En</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url('lang', ['es']) }}">Es</a></li>

routes.php
Route::get('lang/{lang}', 'NotesController@changeLang')->where([ 'lang' => 'en|es']);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function ()
{
 Route::get('notes', 'NotesController@index');
 Route::get('notes/create', 'NotesController@create'); 
});

LangMiddleware.php
        if (!empty(session('lang'))) {
            app()->setLocale(session('lang'));
        }

Comment: Please edit the question to contain the code in your comment.  Having a more complete picture of what code is executing at what time will help clarify the purpose of your application.  In addition, be sure to describe thoroughly the errors or results you're getting and what results you expect or would like to get.

Comment: I did it. Please, check it again and let me know if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was put the middleware in the file **App\Http\Kernel.php** in the section of **protected $middleware = []** because i just only put in the section "protected $routeMiddleware"

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\myNewMiddleware::class,        
];
```